# problem with sd card video door phone

Tags: c, arm, 8051, mmc

I'm working on the code of a video door phone and I'm trying to improve it.

with 16 GB SD card the pictures that the camera takes can be seen on the LCD but when I connect the SD card to PC using a SD card adapter it shows nothing is in the drive.

with 2 GB SD cards it only shows the last taken picture and when I click to see the next photo a black page appears. the core IC is BIT1802 and standard commands provided by spec sheets for MMC and SDSC are utilized. can someone give me a hint about what the problem might be ?

I tried changing the file id that the function FILE_OPEN uses in the main code but it only has effect on the 16 GB sd card and has no effect on the 2 GB sd card and it only shows the last taken picture  i can't show my code here because its too long but i uploaded some parts of it on this link
https://www.avrfreaks.net/forum/problem-sd-card-video-door-phone

Comment: This is too broad; you need to narrow down the problem. Your source need to be posted on this site, formatted and in the form of a minimum example with the _relevant_ parts only. Also has "magic hex numbers" all over it, so it is unlikely that anybody will bother reading it.

Comment: This sounds like you developed a file system of your own?

Comment: you posted conflicting information ... `PC using a SD card adapter it shows nothing is in the drive` ... `it only shows the last taken picture` ..... how can you view a picture that does not exist?

Comment: @jsotola i meant that the microcontroller shows the last picture on lcd but the pc doesn't show it